# Optimization Query with huge data and large group by

Tags: postgresql, optimization, group-by

I have a query that I want to optimize. They consist of a large amount of grouping and joining. Initially, the query was to JOIN first and execute GROUP BY
I wanted to group the columns first and then JOIN the remaining columns.

The problem appears when he performs JOIN operations because no join column was used in GROUP BY.
So, I have no idea how to optimize it

```
SELECT  
            a.create_datetime_date,
            a.company_code,
            a.system_code,
            a.type_id,
            a.status_id,
            a.response_id,
            a.subject_id,
            a.providers_channels_id,
            a.currency,
            a.complaint,
            a.complaint_type,
            a.returned,
-- online
            a.api_type,
            --b.source,
            a.device,
            a.chk_validated,
            a.country,
            a.customer, 
            a.application, 
            a.application_version, 
            a.language,
            a.intercompany,
-- cards
            g.card_brand,
            g.card_type,
            g.mpi_result,
            g.three_ds_type,
            g.operation_category,
            g.credit_card_operation_type,
            g.issuer_country,
-- pos
            a.location_id,
            a.terminal_id,
-- provider_date
            b.subject_id,
            b.providers_channels_id,
            c.card_brand,
            c.card_type,
            c.issuer_country,
            c.three_ds_type,
            c.operation_category,
            c.credit_card_operation_type,
-- agr
             a.trans_count,
             a.trans_value,
             a.turnover_pln,
             a.income_pln,
             a.cost_pln,
             a.time_to_status,
            a.id_array,
            'DAILY_NEW'
--3869958
    FROM    ( SELECT 
            z1.create_datetime_date,
            z1.company_code,
            z1.system_code,
            z1.type_id,
            z1.status_id,
            z1.response_id,
            z1.subject_id,
            z1.providers_channels_id,
            z1.currency,
            z1.complaint,
            z1.complaint_type,
            z1.returned,
            z1.api_type,
            z1.device,
            z1.chk_validated,
            z1.country,
            z1.customer, 
            z1.application, 
            z1.application_version, 
            z1.language,
            z1.intercompany,
            z1.location_id,
            z1.terminal_id,
            count(z1.id) as trans_count,
            sum(z1.value_pln) as trans_value,
            sum(z1.turnover_pln) as turnover_pln,
            sum(z1.income_pln)  as income_pln,
            sum(z1.cost_pln)    as cost_pln,
            sum(z1.extract_epoch) as time_to_status,
            array_agg(z1.id) as  id_array,
             FROM risk.transactions_for_test z1
    WHERE   z1.create_datetime          >= date_trunc('month', date '2020-06-30') - interval '1 month' * 4  AND
            z1.create_datetime          < '2020-06-30'                      AND
            z1.company_code             in ('dotpay')
             
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions b on a.provider_transaction_id=substring(b.external_id, length(b.company_code)+length(b.system_code)+3)
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions_statuses c  on b.id=c.transaction_id and c.is_last=TRUE
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions_statuses g  on a.id=g.transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN risk.dict_statuses    e       on a.status_id=e.id
    WHERE g.is_last =TRUE
```

How you can see, at the first i group and aggregate columns from table A and then i want to join another tables, but  i dont't have mandatory columns in table A (it's subquery with grouping) (for example a.provider_transaction_id and a.id

EDIT:

Output from explain analyze buffers:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=26623251.90..29880446.29 rows=19159967 width=527) (actual time=731329.744..780749.029 rows=3869958 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: ((a.create_datetime)::date), a.company_code, a.system_code, a.type_id, a.status_id, a.response_id, a.subject_id, a.providers_channels_id, a.currency, a.complaint, a.complaint_type, a.returned, a.api_type, (CASE WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%ANDROID%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%IPHONE%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%IPAD%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%WINDOWS%'::text) THEN 'Desktop'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%MACINTOSH%'::text) THEN 'Desktop'::text ELSE 'Other'::text END), a.chk_validated, a.country, a.customer, a.application, a.application_version, a.language, a.intercompany, g.card_brand, g.card_type, g.mpi_result, g.three_ds_type, g.operation_category, g.credit_card_operation_type, g.issuer_country, a.location_id, a.terminal_id, b.subject_id, b.providers_channels_id, c.card_brand, c.card_type, c.issuer_country, c.three_ds_type, c.operation_category, c.credit_card_operation_type"
"  Buffers: shared hit=7974752 read=13700294, temp read=3013159 written=4126575"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=26623251.90..26671151.82 rows=19159967 width=365) (actual time=731329.710..761678.063 rows=33047423 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: ((a.create_datetime)::date), a.system_code, a.type_id, a.status_id, a.response_id, a.subject_id, a.providers_channels_id, a.currency, a.complaint, a.complaint_type, a.returned, a.api_type, (CASE WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%ANDROID%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%IPHONE%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%IPAD%'::text) THEN 'Mobile'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%WINDOWS%'::text) THEN 'Desktop'::text WHEN (upper((a.user_agent)::text) ~~ '%MACINTOSH%'::text) THEN 'Desktop'::text ELSE 'Other'::text END), a.chk_validated, a.country, a.customer, a.application, a.application_version, a.language, a.intercompany, g.card_brand, g.card_type, g.mpi_result, g.three_ds_type, g.operation_category, g.credit_card_operation_type, g.issuer_country, a.location_id, a.terminal_id, b.subject_id, b.providers_channels_id, c.card_brand, c.card_type, c.issuer_country, c.three_ds_type, c.operation_category, c.credit_card_operation_type"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4159856kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=7974752 read=13700294, temp read=3013159 written=4126575"
"        ->  Gather  (cost=19135164.08..22426189.66 rows=19159967 width=365) (actual time=591167.903..639688.023 rows=33047423 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 4"
"              Workers Launched: 4"
"              Buffers: shared hit=7974752 read=13700294, temp read=2493177 written=3606590"
"              ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=19134164.08..20509192.96 rows=4789992 width=365) (actual time=583965.274..621130.313 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                    Hash Cond: (b.id = c.transaction_id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=7974752 read=13700294, temp read=2493177 written=3606590"
"                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=17121862.99..18283927.65 rows=4789992 width=397) (actual time=577937.423..599347.150 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                          Merge Cond: ((a.provider_transaction_id)::text = (""substring""((b.external_id)::text, ((length((b.company_code)::text) + length((b.system_code)::text)) + 3))))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=7496767 read=12528129, temp read=2493177 written=3606590"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=5822528.38..5832924.28 rows=4158360 width=396) (actual time=89454.725..91606.161 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                                Sort Key: a.provider_transaction_id"
"                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1415328kB"
"                                Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1402632kB"
"                                Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1443424kB"
"                                Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1406288kB"
"                                Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1418312kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=478054 read=4234477, temp read=885748 written=885753"
"                                ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=3454200.51..5365366.95 rows=4158360 width=396) (actual time=58629.118..82044.806 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (g.transaction_id = a.id)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=478034 read=4234477"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transactions_statuses g  (cost=0.00..1884282.54 rows=10241484 width=58) (actual time=0.025..19525.597 rows=8172165 loops=5)"
"                                            Filter: is_last"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 10567399"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=478033 read=1172005"
"                                      ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=3387908.45..3387908.45 rows=5303365 width=346) (actual time=58597.628..58597.628 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                                            Buckets: 33554432  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8003456kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3062472"
"                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transactions a  (cost=0.00..3387908.45 rows=5303365 width=346) (actual time=0.061..54622.612 rows=6609485 loops=5)"
"                                                  Filter: ((create_datetime < '2020-06-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((company_code)::text = 'dotpay'::text) AND (create_datetime >= (date_trunc('month'::text, ('2020-06-30'::date)::timestamp with time zone) - '4 mons'::interval)))"
"                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 3804450"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3062472"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=11299334.60..11559682.96 rows=52069672 width=53) (actual time=488480.181..503766.021 rows=18586727 loops=5)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=7018713 read=8293652, temp read=1607429 written=2720837"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=11299334.60..11429508.78 rows=52069672 width=53) (actual time=488480.119..502399.521 rows=18586727 loops=5)"
"                                      Sort Key: (""substring""((b.external_id)::text, ((length((b.company_code)::text) + length((b.system_code)::text)) + 3)))"
"                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4353304kB"
"                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4353304kB"
"                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4353312kB"
"                                      Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4353304kB"
"                                      Worker 3:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4353312kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=7018713 read=8293652, temp read=1607429 written=2720837"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on transactions b  (cost=0.00..3583169.72 rows=52069672 width=53) (actual time=42.577..106061.723 rows=52069673 loops=5)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=7018713 read=8293652"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1884282.54..1884282.54 rows=10241484 width=56) (actual time=5992.972..5992.972 rows=8172165 loops=5)"
"                          Buckets: 67108864  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2494880kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=477873 read=1172165"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transactions_statuses c  (cost=0.00..1884282.54 rows=10241484 width=56) (actual time=1247.782..3608.702 rows=8172165 loops=5)"
"                                Filter: is_last"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 10567399"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=477873 read=1172165"
"Planning Time: 5.222 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 175"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 27.114 ms, Inlining 222.291 ms, Optimization 3565.200 ms, Emission 2446.257 ms, Total 6260.862 ms"
"Execution Time: 781253.458 ms"
```

EDIT 2:
Default query that i want to optimizate:

```
SELECT  
            a.create_datetime::date,
            a.company_code,
            a.system_code,
            a.type_id,
            a.status_id,
            a.response_id,
            a.subject_id,
            a.providers_channels_id,
            a.currency,
            a.complaint,
            a.complaint_type,
            a.returned,
-- online
            a.api_type,
            --b.source,
            case 
                when upper(a.user_agent) like '%ANDROID%'   then 'Mobile'
                when upper(a.user_agent) like '%IPHONE%'    then 'Mobile'
                when upper(a.user_agent) like '%IPAD%'  then 'Mobile'
                when upper(a.user_agent) like '%WINDOWS%'   then 'Desktop'
                when upper(a.user_agent) like '%MACINTOSH%' then 'Desktop'
                else 'Other'
            end,
            a.chk_validated,
            a.country,
            a.customer, 
            a.application, 
            a.application_version, 
            a.language,
            a.intercompany,
-- cards
            g.card_brand,
            g.card_type,
            g.mpi_result,
            g.three_ds_type,
            g.operation_category,
            g.credit_card_operation_type,
            g.issuer_country,
-- pos
            a.location_id,
            a.terminal_id,
-- provider_date
            b.subject_id,
            b.providers_channels_id,
            c.card_brand,
            c.card_type,
            c.issuer_country,
            c.three_ds_type,
            c.operation_category,
            c.credit_card_operation_type,
-- agr
            count(a.id) as trans_count,
            sum(a.value_pln) as trans_value,
            sum(a.turnover_pln) as turnover_pln,
            sum(a.income_pln)   as income_pln,
            sum(a.cost_pln)     as cost_pln,
            sum(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (a.change_datetime - a.create_datetime))) as time_to_status,
            array_agg(a.id),
            'DAILY_NEW'

    FROM    risk.transactions a
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions b on a.provider_transaction_id=substring(b.external_id, length(b.company_code)+length(b.system_code)+3)
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions_statuses c  on b.id=c.transaction_id and c.is_last=TRUE
    LEFT JOIN risk.transactions_statuses g  on a.id=g.transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN risk.dict_statuses    e       on a.status_id=e.id
    WHERE   a.create_datetime           >= date_trunc('month', date '2020-06-30') - interval '1 month' * 4  AND
            a.create_datetime           < '2020-06-30'                      AND
            a.company_code              in ('dotpay')   AND
            g.is_last                   =TRUE
    GROUP by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38)  ;
```

Comment: I used LEFT JOIN LATERAL to unnest array_agg(id), but this change was slower that default.

Comment: Add the `provider_transaction_id` into the inner query and its `GROUP BY` clause. Then join, then aggregate again.

Comment: I've already added `provider_transaction_id` and `id`  in subquery and then join and aggregate again. The results of query is still slower than default.  I had to aggregate twice, firstly in subquery ( 25 level of grouping) and secondly in whole query (45 level of grouping)

Comment: Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output one can only guess.

Comment: `on a.provider_transaction_id=substring(b.external_id, length(b.company_code)+length(b.system_code)+3)` <<-- avoid functions in JOIN-conditions. (and, generally : avoid long strings AS keys)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm going to add output of explain as soon as possible.

Comment: @wildplasser I understand, I was trying to avoid this by adding functional index or single computed column, but without good results

Comment: Also note: `WHERE g.is_last =TRUE ` will degrade a LEFT JOIN into a plain JOIN.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS added

Answer (score 1):

You think it will be faster that way, but PostgreSQL does not.  It thinks the grouping won't actually remove any rows (19159967 both before and after), so that makes it look uninteresting to push the grouping down.

To force it to run the way you want, you can take the subquery named "a" out of the body of the query and put it into a CTE.  That is:

```
WITH a AS MATERIALIZED (<your current subquery a>)
SELECT ... FROM a
LEFT JOIN...
```

The `MATERIALIZED` key word is only needed from PostgreSQL 12 up.  Before that it would always be materialized.

Will this actually be faster?  I don't know, try it and see.

Comment: The above query will not work because it needs id and provider_transaction_id in the subquery what is hard to achieve. The query plan comes from the default query that it wants to optimize. I' ve already edited and added default query.

Comment: @Sebastian If the query won't run, how did you give the plan for it?  Is the plan actually for the "default" query?

Comment: Yes, the plan of query is from 'default' query. I wanted to optimization and i stacked on first query that i mentioned first in this topic.